# Autheracation error: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I keep getting the error `Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key`. It looks like it looses the authCookie, but the `Request.IsAuthenticated`  still is set to true. It's driving my crazy. Also i'm allready handling if the user is not logged in. But the error still appears.

An place where it fails is fore example here

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
      {
        <button class="button-green white">Save</button>
      }
```

But if look at what the user has of properties it still says `IsAuthenticated = true` and the name and Role is also correct, and the ticket is still valid.

This is the callstack

```
 System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
Source=System
ParamName=key
StackTrace:
at System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary.get_Item(Object key)
at System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role)
at ASP._Page_Views_Admin_EditText_cshtml.Execute() in d:\SubVersion\Oline\Project1\Source\Oline.Portal\Views\Admin\EditText.cshtml:line 78
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
InnerException:
```

This is my Custom RoleProvier

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
  var user = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRoles"];
  var ret = new[] { user };
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: What do you have on line 78 in your `EditText.cshtml` view?

Comment: Are you sure you have an Identity set ? And do you have a custom membership provider?

Comment: @Darin. On line 78 is the first code example in my question.
Boas: Yes i can see the my users Identity.  I dont have an custom Membership provider. But i have an CustomRoleprovider. Which is the last example.

Comment: It looks like you are storing the role information in a session variable. Are you sure it was set correctly for the session and it is returning something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was, this section `var user = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRoles"];`, that becomes null. Special then I go back and fort, changing things in Visual Studio 2012. Thanks for the suggestions :)